# Equivalence relation proof digit sum and max

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I need to prove that the following equivalence relation $R$

$aRb \iff a$ and $b$ have the same digit sum

is compatible with the inner relation of $\mathbb N$, which is defined as

$a\circ b := \max \lbrace a,b \rbrace$.

Can you give me any advice or tips?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What exactly is meant by an "inner relation of $\mathbb N$" and what does it mean that an equivalence is "compatible" with that relation?

Comment: @drhab https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Relation_Compatible_with_Operation

Comment: @marco the relation is not compatibe with *max* operation for the set $\{x,y,z\}=\{123,303,200\}$

Comment: @idle Your example is wrong. The digit sum of all numbers is not equal. 123 (1+2+3 = 6), 303 = (6) and 200 is only 2. But they need to be equal as said above.

Comment: @marco I don't know what you are doing here, why you are making a relation between $xRz$ or $yRz$ ? $z$ satisfies a [closed algebraic structure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Closure_(Abstract_Algebra)/Algebraic_Structure) because $max(x,z)$ for whatever $x$ is in the same set.

Comment: @Marco I dunno what do you refer of with $max$, max of digits or max as a number?

Comment: @Idle the maximum of a and b. For example:
a = 11, b = 20. The sum of digits for both is 2 and the maximum is b = 20.

Comment: @Marco in this case, there is no compatibility to prove.

Comment: But I need to... That's one of our exercises.

Comment: $R$ is *not* compatible with $\circ$: for example, $1\mathrel{R}10$, but $1\circ 5=5\not\mathrel{R}10=10\circ 5$. In general, if $a\le b$ and $a\mathrel{R}b$, then $a\circ c\mathrel{R}b\circ c$ iff $c\le a$, $c\ge b$, or $c\mathrel{R}a$.